# A C# Class to work with AT commands?

Tags: c#, at-command

Is there a class for AT communication with devices? Like a class which encapsulates **AT commands** into a **.NET interface**?

It needs to be also able to parse **AT responses** such as *Network Lists*.

Example : *+COPS=?* returns a **list of carriers** and it would take some pretty complex regex to actually parse it. Instead of writing my own lib I want to use a premade one.

**AT Commands** I am refereeing to are these : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set

Comment: Can you link to what AT commands you're referring to?

Comment: @C. Ross, I think he's referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one: [GSM Communication Library](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm). Apart from built in commands it allows you to send any command you need.

Comment: Can't find the source though :(

Comment: Do you need the source code itself? Why not just add the dll as reference and start using it?

Comment: @Nick - Did you ask the developer if source code is available?

Answer (score -1):

I hope this also help you.
This is c# code to send AT commands to your com port device (mobile phone, etc)
This can be used to send sms, etc

```
//Send SMS
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
serialPort.BaudRate = 56700;
serialPort.PortName = "COM3";
serialPort.Open();
serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);//Set Message Format
serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=" + PhoneNumber + (char)(26));
serialPort.WriteLine(MyMessage + System.Environment.NewLine);
serialPort.Close();
```

Comment: No, no, no! Please do not process AT commands in this way. You **MUST** wait for the final result code (e.g. OK, ERROR, ...) before sending the next command. And specifically for AT+CMGS you **MUST** wait for the modem to send "\n\r> " before you should start sending MyMessage. See this answer for more details, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118.