# Connecting 3g modem to the internet with AT commands

Tags: c#, 3g, at-command

Home project, and getting stuck on the topic at hand.

Project is in c#, connecting to serial port, all fine and dandy, then i got stuck trying to get the modem to go online.

Read a bit and first info i got was:

1. Set apn using AT+CGDCONT
2. Dial using ATD"number"

I have the correct settings, and that does more or less nothing. Response from the modem is OK and CONNECT.

After more digging I got somewhere (but still useless) by doing a few things before dialing:

1. AT+CGACT=1 PDP context activation
2. AT+CGDATA="PPP",1 enter data mode

Then i dial in and the led on my modem stops flashing (indicates an active connection) but i still can't access anything online.

Obviously I'm missing something, so i turn to you.

And i would like to do this with AT commands if possible, i can always turn to RAS later :)

Comment: What is the modem? Do you have any specifics on it? I feel like this problem may be too localized for you to get any real help, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Zte 3565-z, shouldn't be the issue i figure it should be doable with the standard at command set which most 3g modems should support.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758618/a-c-sharp-class-to-work-with-at-commands?rq=1

Comment: Would like to do it with no external libs, but will keep that in mind when i give up. Errr if :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave up on AT commands after realizing it's not practical at all. Finished the project by using dotRas for internet connections, and used the modems secondary port to send/receive SMS messages via AT commands and get misc data (network mode, signal strength...)